# Best way to move UIViews in Game (Without User Interaction)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, accelerometer, move

I am searching for a good and fluid way to move multiple `UIViews` over the `Screen` at once. The `Action` should happen when the `Accelerometer` detects acceleration. I have already tried this way:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration{

    CGPoint ObjectPos = Object.center;

    ObjectPos.x -= acceleration.x;

    Object.center = ObjectPos;
}
```

(of course I added some tweaking to improve the movement detection), but all in all, it still is not very fluid.

I hoped there is some way with core animation, but it does not seem to work with the acceleration pretty well.

Help is really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to read this piece of documentation: <strike>[Isolating the Gravity Component from Acceleration Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW11)</strike> and the section below that called 'Isolating Instantaneous Motion from Acceleration Data'.

Basically, you need to filter out gravity in order to get smooth movement. The link provides sample-code.

**Edit**: UIAccelerometer was deprecated in iOS 5.0, and the accompanying documentation seems to be gone as well.

For future reference I did some digging and found, what seems to be, a 'carbon copy' of the original sample code ([source](http://ios-programming.blogspot.nl/2011/11/gyroscope-accelerometer-ios-sdk.html)):

```
// This example uses a low-value filtering factor to generate a value that uses 10 percent of the
// unfiltered acceleration data and 90 percent of the previously filtered value


// Isolating the effects of gravity from accelerometer data
#define kFilteringFactor 0.1
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    // Use a basic low-pass filter to keep only the gravity component of each axis.
    accelX = (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (accelX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
    accelY = (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (accelY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
    accelZ = (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (accelZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
    // Use the acceleration data.
}

// shows a simplified high-pass filter computation with constant effect of gravity.

// Getting the instantaneous portion of movement from accelerometer data
#define kFilteringFactor 0.1
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    // Subtract the low-pass value from the current value to get a simplified high-pass filter
    accelX = acceleration.x - ( (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (accelX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );
    accelY = acceleration.y - ( (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (accelY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );
    accelZ = acceleration.z - ( (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (accelZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );
    // Use the acceleration data.
}
```

Comment: the link doesn't work. someone please remove the link.